# R calculate session duration from overlapping parts

Tags: r, dplyr, intervals

I have a dataset with video streaming playback information.  Each session is split in segments corresponding to when someone paused, moved the playhead forward or backward, etc... 
I'm trying to aggregate streaming playback data in such a way that i don't double count overlapping session segments.  In the simplified example below, for each session A, B, C, i can have more than one playback segment and they can overlap:

```
df<-data.frame(session=c(rep("A",3), rep("B",5), "C"), 
           start=c(1,10,15,1,3,8,14,17,2), 
           end=c(4,18,20,10,5,12,16,20,10))
```

Starting with session A which is in 3 segments, i can use the package Intervals to calculate the non-overlapping session playback time:

```
library(intervals)
x1<-Intervals(df[1:3,c('start','end')])
x1
```

# Object of class Intervals

# 3 intervals over R:

# 1 [1, 4]

# 2 [10, 18]

# 3 [15, 20]

```
interval_intersection(x1)
```

# Object of class Intervals

# 2 intervals over R:

# [1, 4]

# [10, 20]

```
size(interval_intersection(x1))
```

# [1]  3 10

```
sum(size(interval_intersection(x1)))
```

# [1] 13

So this gives me the non-overlapping session duration for session A. Now i'd like to get session duration for all my sessions.  I was hoping i could use something like this with dplyr but I can't seem to be able to integrate Intervals:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
mutate(interval=Intervals(start, end)) %>% 
group_by(session) %>%
summarise(session_duration=sum(size(interval_intersection(interval)))
```

this doesn't work as i can't use the function Intervals in mutate.

I also tried with tapply but that didn't work either:

```
df.intervals<-Intervals(df[c('start','end')])
tapply(df.intervals, df$session, function(x) sum(size(interval_intersection(x))))
```

any ideas welcome!

Comment: Maybe fuzzyjoin

Comment: @mdsumner: I can't see how to use `fuzzyjoin` here, could you develop? I would be really interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't begin with a `mutate` because the result is not a vector of length `nrow(df)`, but an "Object of class Intervals" (even though it contains `nrow(df)` intervals).

So you simply have to do the grouping first:

```
library(intervals)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(session) %>%
  summarise(session_duration = sum(size(interval_intersection(Intervals(c(start, end))))))

# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   session session_duration
#    <fctr>            <dbl>
# 1       A               13
# 2       B               16
# 3       C                8
```